# How do I plot separated Y-axis in one 2-D coordinate system in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot like this [image].How to plot this figure in Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to use SUBPLOT to plot several subplots on top of each other, and link the x-axis with `linkaxes(h,'x')`. Sample code:

```
numGraphs = 5;
 x = -20 + (20+20)*rand(numGraphs,30);
figure;
for i=1:numGraphs
   h(i) = subplot(numGraphs,1,i);
   plot(x(i,:));
   h(i).XAxisLocation = 'origin';
   box(h(i), 'off')
end
linkaxes(h,'x')
```

It will synchronise the x-axis of multiple graphs and you will have something like:

[image]

Comment: This is definitely the way to go!